# xcode 7 indexes forever...won't compile

Tags: indexing, compilation, xcode7

Xcode 7 compiles properly on the simulator but won't do so on iPhone or iPad because the indexing never finishes. Code is all Objective C...not Swift, which has been mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: I'm seeing VERY sluggish indexing behaviour from Xcode... about 10 to 30 times slower than Xcode 6.